# System load indicator does not indicate network activity for Huawei dongles

Tags: indicator

I have `System load indicator` installed which works perfectly except it shows no activity when I connect to the internet via a USB dongle. It works well when I connect via WiFi or Ethernet cable. How is this so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug open for this issue. Please follow this link and click the "affects me" button: https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-multiload/+bug/798649